# transitionend isn't catched in a listener inside Navigator's initialRouteName component (React Native 0.71.11)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, transitionend

```
export const MyNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator screenOptions={options} initialRouteName={ initialScreen}>
      <Screen name={someScreen} component={someComponent} />
      <Screen name={someScreen} component={someComponent} />
      <Screen name={someScreen} component={someComponent} />
      <Screen name={someScreen} component={someComponent} />
    </Navigator>
  )
})
```

I use the navigation prop in the initialScreen component and set a listener to transitionEnd.
For some reason, this is not caught when I navigate from screen to screen. BTW "state" event is being catched.

Tried to put the addListener in other components - inside the component it works